# How can I drop the index of a Pandas Series (pandas.core.series.Series) to return a numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to show a confusion matrix for predicted test data (binary text classification). But I can't get `y_pred` to match `y_test` after running `model.predict()`.

First, let's look at the test/true data:

```
y_test = (y_test > 0.5)
print(y_test)
print(type(y_test))
```

Output:

```
2       False
17       True
18       True
...
4980     True
4986    False
4990     True
pandas.core.series.Series
```

The missing indexes are contained in the training set.

Here's what happens when we predict based on test data:

```
y_pred = model.predict(data_test)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5)
print(y_pred)
print(type(y_pred))
```

Output:

```
[[ True]
 [ True]
 [ True]
 [False]
 ...
 [ True]
 [ True]
 [ True]]
numpy.ndarray
```

Test/True data:

```
y_test = (y_test > 0.5)
print(y_test)
```

Output:

```
2       False
17       True
18       True
...
4980     True
4986    False
4990     True
```

Ultimately I'm looking to build a confusion matrix, but the data isn't the same format.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

**What do you recommend?**

**Attempts so far:**

```
y_test_np = y_test.values
```

Output:

```
[False  True  True ... True False  True]
```

Closer, but it looks like I need each item to also be an array (e.g. `[[ True] [False] [ True]]`). How can I align the arrays?

Comment: It would be helpful if you just provided example data for `y_test` and `y_pred` in a minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks @gofvonx. Here's sample data: `df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["label", "text"], data=[[1,'foo bar'],[1,'bar baz'],[0,'baz qux'],[1,'foo qux'],[0,'quux foo'],[0,'baz quuz'],[1,'corge foo'],[0,'corge bar'],[1,'corge grault'],[1,'foo waldo']])
` and a rough `ipynb` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683743/how-can-i-build-a-confusion-matrix-for-a-binary-text-classification-model

Answer (score 0):

Just for illustration let's create some sample data.

```
y_test = pd.Series([True, False])
y_pred = np.array([[True], [False]])
```

You can convert the pandas Series `y_test` to a numpy array

```
y_test.values
```

and `squeeze` the numpy array `y_pred` to obtain the same shape

```
numpy.squeeze(y_pred)
```

Comment: Closer. `y_test.values` leads to `[False  True  True ... True False  True]`, but `np.squeeze(y_pred)` still leads to `[[ True]  [ True] ...  [ True]]`.

Comment: @Ryan What is `y_pred,shape`? You might need to use the keyword argument `axis` in `numpy.squeeze`.

Comment: Thanks @Ryan for the link. I generated `y_pred` with the code from the thread linked. `np.squeeze` produces the desired result. Be aware however that `y_pred.shape` might still be different from `y_test.shape.values` as you seem to do more tests. You need to slice `y_pred` accordingly, but this is a different [topic](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html).